# Is it possible to choose 10 points from 20000 with that property?

Tags: combinatorial-geometry

A set of $20000$ points is chosen in a ball  of radius $6$ in $ \mathbb{R}^3 $. Do there exist $10$ ones of these points s. t. all the distances between them are less than or equal to $1$?

Comment: What do you means as ''points''? are they little balls with some radius $\ne 0$  such that the $20000$ fill the ball?

Comment: @Emilio Novati: See [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-dimensional_space) for the standard definition.

Comment: Are the original $20000$ points equally spaced inside the sphere, if not what is the significance of $20000$?

Comment: @ Rammus; I don't understand " equally spaced inside the sphere". These points are in general position.

Comment: If the ball of radius $6$ can be completely covered by $2222$ balls of radius $\frac12$, then the answer is yes: by the pigeonhole principle, one of those $2222$ balls must contain at least $10$ points, which will all be within a distance $1$ of one another. I don't know offhand whether $2222$ balls of radius $\frac12$ can cover the ball of radius $6$; but the large ball has the same volume as only $1728$ small balls, so it's a reasonable bet.

Comment: @ Greg Martin: there is a difference between a proof and  plausible reasoning.

Comment: @GregMartin I'm not sure that we can in fact cover the entire volume of the ball with the spheres; they need to overlap a little bit and the size of the circumscribed sphere of a tetrahedron suggests they might need to have too large an overlap to limit ourselves to $2222$ unit-diameter spheres.

Comment: In any ball of any radius there are infinitely many (uncountable) points and infinitely many of these points has distance less than any non zero value  . So, what is your question?

Comment: @Emilio Novati: These $20000$ points are chosen in a fixed ball of radius $6 $ in $\mathbb{R}^3.$ The question has just been  formulated more exactly.

Comment: @user64494 : if you would prefer that people not post ideas unless they had a complete proof, then by all means say so in your writeup.